# How to optionally configure root_block_device in EC2 instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating AWS EC2 instance using terraform. The instance will be created using the provided ami id. In terraform the `root_block_device` block can be used to configure root volume.
I want to make this configuration optional based on the variable. So if `root_block_override` variable is true then use provided values; else use the root volume configuration from the image.

The terraform below throws error `An argument named "count" is not expected here.`

How to configure the root optionally?

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami                    = var.ami_id
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2.name
  key_name               = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
  user_data_base64       = base64encode(templatefile(var.user_data_file_path, var.user_data_variables))
  root_block_device {
    count                 = var.root_block_override ? 1 : 0
    delete_on_termination = var.root_block_delete_on_termination
    encrypted             = true
    iops                  = var.root_block_volume_type == "gp2" ? null : var.root_block_iops
    kms_key_id            = var.root_block_kms_key_id
    throughput            = var.root_block_throughput
    volume_size           = var.root_block_volume_size
    volume_type           = var.root_block_volume_type
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `for_each` [1] meta-argument and `dynamic` [2] block:

```
  dynamic "root_block_device" {
    for_each = var.root_block_override ? [1] : []
    content {
      delete_on_termination = var.root_block_delete_on_termination
      encrypted             = true
      iops                  = var.root_block_volume_type == "gp2" ? null : var.root_block_iops
      kms_key_id            = var.root_block_kms_key_id
      throughput            = var.root_block_throughput
      volume_size           = var.root_block_volume_size
      volume_type           = var.root_block_volume_type
   }
  }
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks